# Hide TabBar in Xamarin Forms Shell

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.shell

I wan't to hide the TabBar in a Xamarin Forms Shell 4.0.0.497661 project.

I try using:

```
Shell.SetTabBarIsVisible(Shell.Current, false);
```

After the page has loaded and drawed, but it has no effect.

If I put in the codebehind .cs constructor after **InitializeComponent();** a null reference exception has launched, but this isn't the problem for me.

How can I hide the TabBar at start or after started?

**EDIT:**

At last, I have no way to hide bottom bar then...
The bottom bar appears when FlyoutItem is included on the Shell, like:

```
<FlyoutItem Route="animals"
            Title="Animals"
            FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsMultipleItems">

    <ShellContent Route="cats"
                Title="... />
```

If I remove the FlyoutItem, no bottom bar is displayed.

No other way found to remove it!
But it solves my problem.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`TabBarIsVisible` is an [attached property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/attached-properties) of `Shell`. You should pass the page as the first parameter in the `SetTabBarIsVisible` to tell the shell hiding its tab bar. Use it like:

```
public AppShell()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Shell.SetTabBarIsVisible(this, false);
}
```

You can also place it on any page which you don't need the tab bar.

Answer (score 11):

In my case, I need to remove tabbar from child page, then: ***Shell.TabBarIsVisible="False"***

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             Title="Child page from shell"
             Shell.TabBarIsVisible="False"
             x:Class="AppMvvm.Views.User.LoginPage/>
```

Answer (score 6):

Sorry, don't have enough rep. to comment.

In which class are you doing `Shell.SetTabBarIsVisible(Shell.Current, false);`?

Is it the `Shell` or `Current` that is null if you put it after the constructor?

Edit 30/6/2019:

I have tested a few things in Shell. 
Here's a link to the project: https://github.com/JesperBaltzersen/ShellTest
In the class `Content1.Xaml.cs` there's a button handler that toggles the tabbar:

```
    public bool NavVisible { get; set; }

    void OnButtonTapped(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        NavVisible = !NavVisible;
        Shell.SetNavBarIsVisible(this, NavVisible);
    }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: In the AppShell, but meybe I have any problem with the Nuget version or something. I solved removing the FlyoutItem and using MenuItem in the Shell.

Answer (score 4):

Another approach:

```
<Shell 
X:Class="..............:
xmlns:sd="..................."
Shell.IsTabBarVisible="False">

</Shell>
```